# Twilio - Disable SMS for a Specific Number Using the API

Tags: api, twilio

On this page:
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181528-Billing-for-incoming-SMS-messages

It says that we can remove the SMS URL manually or with the API, but there's no link to the 'API' and I can't find what API endpoint I should call to configure the 'WebHook URLS'?

How can I configure the URL WebHook using the API?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you need to call the API at:
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/IncomingPhoneNumbers/{IncomingPhoneNumberSid}

The [example given with the Python API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers) to get the specific number:

```
number = client.phone_numbers.get("PN2a0747eba6abf96b7e3c3ff0b4530f6e")
```

To update the number:
number =

```
client.phone_numbers.update("PN2a0747eba6abf96b7e3c3ff0b4530f6e", voice_url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    sms_url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/sms.xml")
```